# img-circle going outside margin

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I've created an `img-circle` to be placed on the same `row` as a paragraph of text using two `.col-xs-6,` but my image is spilling over the margin of the `container`.

I have tried changing the `padding` to 0, but that didn't work.

I don't have any CSS styling for the `img-circle` currently.

```
<div class="container about">
     <div class="row">
          <div class="col-xs-6">
                 <p class="hello">Hello,</p>
          </div>
      </div>
      <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-6">
                 <p class="intro">text from paragraph here</p>
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-6">
                 <img class="profile-pic img-circle" src="#"/> 
            </div>
      </div>
```

Comment: please provide jsfiddle or example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to use class `.img-responsive` in `img`, see Bootstrap [Docs](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#images)

> Images in Bootstrap 3 can be made responsive-friendly via the addition
>   of the `.img-responsive` class. This applies `max-width: 100%;`,
>   `height: auto;` and `display: block;` to the image so that it scales nicely to the parent element.

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="container about">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-6">
      <p class="hello">Hello,</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-6">
      <p class="intro">text from paragraph here</p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-6">
      <img class="profile-pic img-circle img-responsive" src="//lorempixel.com/1000/1000" />
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```